# PHP mysqli query error but query is correct

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a MySQL Query which executes correctly in SequelPro but doesnt execute in PHP Mysqli. The message which is shown:

> Execution stopped.
>   Message: An error occured when executing sql-statement: SET @csum := 0; select kunde, sales, (@csum := @csum + cr.sales) as cumulative_sales FROM (and the whole query (too long for printing it here)

I tried it a few times in Sequel PRo and it works.
and the query is stored in the variable $toBeExecuted
also printed it out to check if its correct and it is.

```
return mysqli_query($this->connectionTargetDB, $toBoExecuted);
```

I guess theres a problem with SET @csum := 0

/edit
The whole Query:

```
SET @csum := 0;
select kunde, sales, (@csum := @csum + cr.sales) as cumulative_sales
  FROM (
SELECT j.kunde as kunde,
       ROUND(SUM(m.ausgangsrechnungen - m.eingangsrechnungen), 2) as sales
  FROM jobs_per_month m,
       jobs j,
       temporal_dates t
 WHERE day(t._date) = 1
   AND (t._date BETWEEN date_add(now(), INTERVAL -12 MONTH) and now())
   AND m.monat = month(t._date)
   AND m.jahr = year(t._date)
   AND j.internal_jobnr = m.internal_jobnr
 GROUP BY j.kunde
HAVING sales >= 10000
 UNION ALL
SELECT concat(COUNT(r.sales), ' Kunde < 10k') as kunde,
       ROUND(SUM(r.sales), 2) as sales
  FROM (SELECT j.kunde as kunde,
       ROUND(SUM(m.ausgangsrechnungen - m.eingangsrechnungen), 2) as sales
  FROM jobs_per_month m,
       jobs j,
       temporal_dates t
 WHERE day(t._date) = 1
   AND (t._date BETWEEN date_add(now(), INTERVAL -12 MONTH) and now())
   AND m.monat = month(t._date)
   AND m.jahr = year(t._date)
   AND j.internal_jobnr = m.internal_jobnr
 GROUP BY j.kunde
HAVING sales < 10000 AND sales > 0) r
 ORDER by sales desc) cr
```

Comment: Pastebin your sql query.

Comment: We really need to see the entire thing to help hard to understand.

Comment: @Sand added above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured the answer out myself. 
The problem was as I said in `SET @csum := 0;`
I dont know why but it works when I do a `CROSS JOIN (SELECT @csum:=1) c` 
after the last `FROM` in the statement.

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty obvious.

What you have here is not an SQL query, but a *set* of multiple queries.
Whereas mysqli_query is intended to run only one query.

Therefore you should make two calls,

```
$this->connectionTargetDB->query("SET @csum := 0");
return $this->connectionTargetDB->query($toBoExecuted);
```